# Python Script greping directories

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a if statement from Shell Script and trying to re write this into python..
but I have no idea how it works in python.

`if [[ $(ls -d $DIR1/* | grep test) ]]`

Above is the shell script.. and I want to rewrite this in python language. 
what it does is it looks for any directories that starts with the word "TEST" 
in DIR1 and if there is, it should execute the command in if..

how can I do this python?

I will edit the question.. 
Lets say my `DIR1` is `/tmp/doc` and in `/doc` directories, there are test1, test2, get1 ,get2...

I want to use if statement to check if inside of the `/doc` directories contains any directories that contains the word `"test"` (in this case `test1` and `test2`)

if yes, I want to move that `test1` and `test2` to other directories.

Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate further on the if command here. Is this something that you want to happen inside a python script or do you want python to return something for your shell script to work with?

Comment: I want to rewrite this in python script. So I am converting from shell script to python script. which means it should be IN Python

Comment: What's the value of `$DIR` ?

Comment: DIR1 is the directory path to the directory that i want to check

Comment: @Young, your question and accepted answer have very little in common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.listdir` in conjunction with `os.path.isdir`:

```
path = 'YOUR/FOLDER'
# get all files in path
all_files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.startswith("test")]
# filter to keep only directories
folders = filter(os.path.isdir, all_files)
```

Now you can use the fact that an empty list evaluates to `False`:

```
if folders:
    print "has folders!"
```

Comment: how is this getting all the "test" directories only?  I don't see how it is working.. for example.. In my DIR1 there are test1 test2 get2 and I want to use this if statement to see if there is a directories that starts with test if yes than call move that test1 and test2 directories.

Comment: @Young add `startswith` to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.listdir` to get all the contents in the directory, use `os.path.isdir` and `d.startswith("test")` to find the directories starting with "test"

```
import os
path = "/tmp/doc"

print([d for d in os.listdir(path)
   if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, path))
   and d.startswith("test")])
```

If case does not matter use `d.lower().startswith("test")`

To move use `shutil.move`:

```
import os
import shutil

path = "/DIR1/"
test_dirs = (d for d in os.listdir(path)
       if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d,path ))
       and d.startswith("test"))

for d in test_dirs:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(d,path),"your/dest/path")
```

Or do it all in a single loop:

```
for d in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d,path )) and d.startswith("test"):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(d, path), "your/dest/path")
```

To find dirs starting with `test`  you can simply use  `ls -d $DIR1/test*/`

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively direct equivalent of your script. Note your `grep` doesn't check if the directory actually *starts*  with 'test', just if it is found anywhere, so this code does the same:

```
import os
import glob

DIR1 = 'dir1'
pattern = os.path.join(DIR1, '*')
if any(os.path.isdir(f) and 'test' in f for f in glob.glob(pattern)):
    do whatever
```